# htaccess url rewrite including more than one parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to use htaccess to write the following:-

```
main.php?section=message&page=inbox&f=20&id=1
```

I wish to change it into:-

```
message/inbox?f=20&id=1
```

and I tried:-

```
RewriteRule    ^message/inbox?f=$([A-Za-z0-9-]+)&id=$([A-Za-z0-9-]+)   main.php?section=message&page=inbox&f=$1&id=$2
```

and it give me server error.

How shall I improve the rewriting?

Comment: The `%{QUERY_STRING}` is not handled in RewriteRules. If you don't rename the parameters, don't bother with relisting them. Use the QSA flag as explained in the Apache manual.

Comment: Could you please give me more hints? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand... Can you give me an example on the rewriting format? Thanks.

Comment: The example you give seems not the same as my target format...

Comment: nice question +1 for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)?f=(.*)&id=(.*)$ /main.php?section=$1&page=$2&f=$3&id=$4 [L]
```

**OR**

```
RewriteRule ^message/inbox?f=20&id=1$ main.php?section=message&page=inbox&f=20&id=1 [L]
```